# Vite React Library mode, path alias error in dist

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am building a library with Vite, React and ts.
I am able to use path alias while developing, so everything is working good inside the lib folder,

But the problem is when I build my library to prepare to be used outside, in the dist folder that is generated the path alias seems not to be working fine, since the modules are not found...

```
Cannot find module '@/domain
```

my vite.config.js file is

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    fs: {
      allow: [".."],
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      formats: ["es"],
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "lib/index.tsx"),
      fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
      name: PackageData.name,
    },
    sourcemap: false,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: isModuleExternal,
      plugins: [
        typescript({
          // Required, since test and build behave differently
          tsconfig:
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
              ? "./tsconfig.json"
              : "./tsconfig.development.json",
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tsconfigPaths({
      // Required, since test and build behave differently
      projects:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? ["./tsconfig.json"]
          : ["./tsconfig.development.json"],
    }),
    react({
      jsxRuntime: "automatic",
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          [
            "babel-plugin-styled-components",
            {
              displayName: true,
              fileName: false,
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./lib/src"),
    },
  },
});
```

and my ts config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./lib/src/*"]
    },
  "files": ["global.d.ts"],
  "include": ["./lib", "../src"]
}
```

Comment: Did you end up resolving this problem?